# How to link libcurl, libssl, uuid libs statically?

Tags: cmake, aws-sdk-cpp

Running this command: `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DENABLE_TESTING=OFF -DBUILD_ONLY="s3" -DFORCE_SHARED_CRT=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF <aws-sdk-src>` always links to shared libcurl, ssl libraries as you can see from (truncated) CMAKE output:

```
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.8") 
--   Zlib include directory: /usr/include
--   Zlib library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so
-- Encryption: Openssl
-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so (found version "1.0.2g") 
--   Openssl include directory: /usr/include
--   Openssl library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
-- Http client: Curl
-- Found CURL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so (found version "7.47.0") 
--   Curl include directory: /usr/include
--   Curl library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so
-- Considering s3
```

How can I force it to link libz.a, libcurl.a instead?

Answer (score 0):

As libraries are searched mostly by [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_library.html) command, you may set variable [CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES.html) for affect on extensions which are searched.

By specifying single extension with

```
-DCMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES=.a
```

you will force to *search only* static libraries.

By specifying several extensions with

```
"-DCMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES=.a;.so"
```

you tell CMake to *prefer* static libraries (`.a`) over shared ones (`.so`).

Comment: Tried -DCMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES, but it doesn't work. It is still linking to shared libraries. No errors. I verified static libs are present right next to shared libraries.

Comment: yes. I made sure I'm starting clean. Basically deleted all CMake generated files before running command with -DCMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES option.